# SQL: How to make table name in stored procedure dynamic

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic

I am pretty new to SQL Server and hope someone here can help me with this (I'm using QL Server 2008).

The following is a small procedure that works as intended.

Now I would like to use the same procedure to update multiple tables as all these tables have exactly the same column names and column formatting, the only difference is the 2nd part of the table name for which I added `XXX` below.

Can someone tell me how this could be made dynamic and also provide me some explanations on this ?
I cannot provide much more here as I wasn't sure about how to approach this - other than probably declaring `@sql nvarchar(max)` and wrapping the whole query in `SET @sql = N'...'` before executing it.

My stored procedure:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Cal_UpdateTeam]
        @team nvarchar(100),
        @teamID int,
        @notes nvarchar(1000),
        @log nvarchar(100),
        @admin varchar(50)
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        BEGIN   

        IF NOT EXISTS 
        (
                SELECT  * 
                FROM    Cal_XXX
                WHERE   teamID = @teamID
        )
        INSERT INTO Cal_XXX
        (
                team,
                teamID,
                notes,
                log,
                admin
        )
        SELECT  @team,
                @teamID,
                @notes,
                @log,
                @admin
        ELSE
                UPDATE  Cal_XXX
                SET     team = @team,
                        teamID = @teamID,
                        notes = @notes,
                        log = @log,
                        admin = @admin
                WHERE   teamID = @teamID

        END
END
```

Many thanks for any tips and advise on this, Mike.

Comment: "all these tables have exactly the same column names and column formatting".  This is usually a sign of poor database design.  You should have one table, with a column to distinguish between the "XXX"s.  If you had a good design, then you wouldn't be struggling with this stored procedure, for instance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic Datasource in SQL Server Stored Procudure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874538/dynamic-datasource-in-sql-server-stored-procudure)

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Thanks for this. Yes, they all have the same column names but some of them have additional columns that are not needed for my query.

Comment: @Mike: The common attributes should be in a single common table; the specific attributes should be in sub-type tables.

Comment: Thanks, Both. I am not sure it makes sense to combine all the tables here in one as these are used to generate a navbar where each level of the navbar has its own table and they are linked between each other as every level has children on the level below. If I would combine them then the links would be within the same table.

Answer (score 9):

you should wrap your sql query in an nvarchar and then execute that query as in the below example :

```
    declare @sql nvarchar(max)
    declare @TableName nvarchar(max)
    set @TableName = 'mytable'
    set @sql = 'Select * from ' + @TableName
    Exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: This worked for me. This should be marked as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

in SP you can use Temporary Tables fro example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SELECT_TABLE
    @REQUEST_ID INT
AS
BEGIN

/*************************************
** Temporary table                  **
*************************************/
    CREATE TABLE #SOURCE (
        ID        INT
      , ID_PARENT INT
      , NAME      VARCHAR(200)
      , SORT      INT
      ..
      ..
    )

IF @REQUEST_ID = 'YES' BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #SOURCE SELECT * FROM SOURCE_A
END
ELSE BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #SOURCE SELECT * FROM SOURCE_B
END

SELECT * FROM #SOURCE
.....


END

GO
```

in SP you can encapsulate other SPs with different table names like parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SELECT_FROM_TABLE_A
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM SOURCE_A
END
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE SELECT_FROM_TABLE_B
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM SOURCE_B
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE SELECT_TABLE
    @REQUEST_ID INT

AS
BEGIN

/**********************************************
** Subrequest select                         **
**********************************************/

    IF @REQUEST_ID = 'YES' BEGIN
        -- Request SP fro Source A
        EXEC SELECT_FROM_TABLE_A
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        -- Request SP fro Source B
        EXEC SELECT_FROM_TABLE_B
    END
END
GO
```