# How to pass a table variable from one stored procedure to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

My scenario is like this,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_1
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #tmpTable(ID, Value)
    VALUES(1, 1), (2, 2)
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE SP_2
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #tmpTable(ID INT, Value INT)
    EXEC SP_1

    SELECT * FROM #tmpTable

    DROP TABLE #tmpTable
END
GO

EXEC SP_2
GO

DROP PROCEDURE SP_1
DROP PROCEDURE SP_2
```

I want to replace this `#` table with a `TABLE VARIABLE` (`@` Table).

I tried to passed table variable as parameter to SP_1 but I should pass table variable as read only parameter. Since it's read only I can't insert into the table variable inside SP_1. Is there any other way I can accomplish this?

Comment: You will need to create a `TABLE TYPE` then Declare a parameter of that type and yes it will be a read-only param but then you can get data into another table variable or temp table inside your param and do whatever you want to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not gonna work this way. you should encapsulate your query within a string. once done you can change the table names as you like. and then, execute using EXEC sp_executesql.
i've previously answered a similar question which can be found below:
[SQL: How to make table name in stored procedure dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25340658/sql-how-to-make-table-name-in-stored-procedure-dynamic/25341122#25341122)
here's the example i've provided

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
    declare @TableName nvarchar(max)
    set @TableName = 'mytable'
    set @sql = 'Select * from ' + @TableName
    Exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me(Sql server 2012), although I did not completely understand what you are trying to achieve:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_1
AS 
BEGIN

    Create table #tmpTable (ID INT, Value INT)

    INSERT INTO #tmpTable(ID, Value)
    VALUES(1, 1), (2, 2)

    Select ID,Value from #tmpTable
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE SP_2
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @tmpTable table (ID INT, Value INT)

    Insert into @tmpTable
    EXEC SP_1

    SELECT * FROM @tmpTable


END
GO

EXEC SP_2
GO

DROP PROCEDURE SP_1
DROP PROCEDURE SP_2
```

Comment: Just want to add that SP_1 can return the result set with or without a table variable or temp table for this task.  The INSERT...EXEC statement uses the returned result set regardless of the source.  Also, the `SP_` prefix should not be used for user stored procedures as that is reserved for system procs, although that might just be name used for the example @Sandeep provided.

Comment: @Dan: Completely agree. I just used the name of the proc as specified in Sandeep's example. I hope it is just an example and not actual code. Also, I believe there would be more processing before 'select'ing the results. As such I have put the code from Sandeep's example as is. Idea was to just point out how this could be done.

Answer (score -1):

I prefer passing data around as [xml]. It's easier to work with for me. You could build your record set similar to the code below and pass [xml] parameters between your procedures, then parse it out as shown.

declare @record_list [xml] = (select *

   from   [sys].[objects]

   for xml path(N'record'), root(N'record_list'));

select @record_list;

select t.c.value(N'(./schema_id/text())[1]', N'[sysname]')   as [schema_id]

       , t.c.value(N'(./name/text())[1]', N'[sysname]')      as [name]

       , t.c.value(N'(./object_id/text())[1]', N'[sysname]') as [object_id]

from   @record_list.nodes(N'/record_list/record') as t(c);